# Find unused variables in Flash Builder 4 (like Eclipse for Java does)

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, actionscript-3, eclipse-plugin, flash-builder

Eclipse has a built in functionality to find unused variables (and methods too I guess). Flash Builder 4 is built on top of Eclipse but it doesn't have that functionality. Do you know any plugin to achieve that functionality? Also, if you know any other kind of plugin besides SourceMate to improve Flash Builder let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use [FlexPMD](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexpmd/FlexPMD) which has [corresponding Eclipse plugin](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexpmd/FlexPMD+Eclipse+plugin).

Comment: Try to use it from command line first and then return to the plugin :)

Comment: It works on the command line but on the FlexPMD View it doesn't. Thanks for your help. I have another problem now :P

Comment: I got it. I can't have white spaces on my workspace location. Thanks =)

Comment: How can you highlight the unused variables with this? I've installed it for Flash Builder but even when I create an unused variable and run FlexPMD afterwards, it gives me a bunch of other warnings and errors, but none of them points out the unused variable.

Comment: I got it to work to find unused *Local Variables*, but can't seem to identify unused member variables (private, protected, public, etc.)