# Is there a tool that can track unused code automatically

Tags: apache-flex, code-cleanup, flex-pmd

I currently have 6 different flex applications (widgets) that run on a main page.
They all depend on one common library project.

I am currently cleaning up the codebase quite dramatically and it is hard to keep overview this way especially since I inherited the codebase.

Does anyone know a tool that can automatically inform me of any dead code?

Cheers

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find unused variables in Flash Builder 4 (like Eclipse for Java does)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100602/find-unused-variables-in-flash-builder-4-like-eclipse-for-java-does)

Comment: It is not a duplicate since in that topic, it is not specified whether FlexPMD also looks into library projects.
Therefore, my somewhat more specific question.

Comment: If you're talking about finding unused classes in general. Try this:
http://blog.tomschober.com/2011/02/implementing-orphan-finder-for-your-flex-app/

Comment: Unused classes are a bit too general.
With unused code I meant variables, methods, classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few tools out there.  I'd start with this [one from Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash-builder/articles/ascode-coverage.html); which I believe is written as an eclipse plugin.

[FlexPMD](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexpmd/FlexPMD) is another tool; also from Adobe.

[FlexCover](http://code.google.com/p/flexcover/) is another.

Keep in mind that the Flex Compiler will automatically remove unused classes from your final SWF; so removing these classes from your project will probably not affect the final SWF size.  I can see it helping with long-term maintenance, though..

Comment: I know that the flex compiler will not add any unused classes.
However due to the inherited codebase, I have loads of monster classes with 800+ lines so I will have to go at it function by function :(

Comment: Yeah, i can understand why you'd want to try to clean out some unused functions.  I blanked on the FlexPMD name; it is another similar style tool and I'll add that to my answer.